# ANTLR4 - Whitespace as separator

Tags: parsing, antlr

I have the following grammar.
My grammar needs to accept these kind of statements:

X IN (10,20,30)

X IN (10 20 30)

```
expr
   : expr IN '(' constant_list ')'  #InExp
    ;
    
constant_list
    : constant ((',') constant)*
    ;
    
constant
    : numeric_constant
    | character_constant
    ;
    
SPACE
    : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
    ;
```

I just tried to edit the rule `constant_list` to:

```
constant_list
    : constant ((','|SPACE) constant)*
    ;
```

But the spaces ate being ignored. How can I handle this situation? Do I need to use the Hidden Channel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't use the `SPACE` token in your parser rules: they are skipped (discarded from the lexer).

What you could do is this:

```
constant_list
 : constant (','? constant)*
 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved editing the rule:

```
constant_list
    : constant (',' constant)*
    | constant ( constant)*
    ;
```

Comment: That's the same like what @BartKiers suggested, just not as compact (and hence slightly slower).